# How to resize label in pyqtgraph to prevent overlapping axis labels and tick labels?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, font-size, axis-labels, pyqtgraph

After resizing the axis label and tick label, pyqtgraph has them overlapped.  The example code below shows the yaxis label and tick label displaying on top of each other.  How to solve this problem?

I've tried setting tickTextWidth and tickTextHeight in AxisItem, but it doesn't seem to work. (see code below, the commented out code doesn't seem to do anything)

```
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10000)
x2 = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10000)
y = x/10000 + x2/1000

win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
plot = win.addPlot(x=x, y=y, title="Plot")
label_style = {'color': '#EEE', 'font-size': '20pt'}
plot.setLabel('bottom', "some x axis label", **label_style)
plot.setLabel('left', "some y axis label")
plot.getAxis('left').setLabel(**label_style)

font=QtGui.QFont()
font.setPixelSize(20)
plot.getAxis("bottom").tickFont = font
plot.getAxis("bottom").setStyle(tickTextOffset=20)
plot.getAxis("left").tickFont = font
plot.getAxis("left").setStyle(tickTextOffset=20)
# plot.getAxis("left").setStyle(tickTextOffset=20, tickTextHeight=20, tickTextWidth=20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

What offset or internal setting should I change?

Comment: Well.. Okay.. I've found out that `plot.getAxis("left").setWidth(130)`  can work to fix the overlap, but that won't work when the yaxis tick sig dig changes.